Confused about a derivation in Proposition 8.3.1 in Hawking and Ellis
I'm working through the proof of Proposition 8.3.1 in Hawking and Ellis (1973, pp. 278-80) about the equivalence between $b$-completeness of a Lorentzian manifold and $m$-completeness of its associated orthogonal frame bundle, and I'm confused about the following passage:

Let $u \in \lambda(t)$ [for $\lambda(t)$ a curve in the orthogonal frame bundle $O(M)$]. Then one can construct a horizontal curve $\overline{\lambda}(t)$ through $u$ such that $\pi(\overline{\lambda}(t)) = \pi(\lambda(t))$. For each value of $t$, $\lambda(t)$, and $\overline{\lambda}(t)$ will lie on the same fibre, so there will be a unique curve $B(t)$ in $O(3,1)$ such that $\lambda(t) = B(t)\overline{\lambda}(t)$. This implies
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_\lambda = B_* \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_{\overline{\lambda}} + F((dB/dt)B^{-1})$$

I don't understand the second term on the RHS above:

Where does it come from? It's hard for me to make sense of $B(t)\overline{\lambda}(t)$ as a product or something like that, so I thought of $B$ as a smooth map from $O(M)$ to $O(M)$ which composed with smooth $\overline{\lambda}: [0, a) \rightarrow O(M)$, gives a smooth map from $[0, a)$ to $O(M)$. And then:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_\lambda := \lambda_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) = B(\overline{\lambda}(t))_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) =: B_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_\overline{\lambda}$$
with $(\partial/\partial t)$ a vector field in manifold-with-boundary $[0, a)$. What's wrong with this reasoning?

What is $F$ on the RHS? Hawking and Ellis do not say explicitly, and I can't infer it from the context.


EDIT: I think I got what's going on, but the resulting reasoning strikes me as overly complicated, and there are still some uncertain steps. I'd be grateful if someone could improve it.
My reasoning in 1) above is mistaken, because $B(t)$, as a curve in $O(3,1)$, may be considered both as a map $B: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow O(3,1)$ and as a one-parameter family of maps $B: \mathbb{R} \times O(M) \rightarrow O(M)$ with $B_t: O(M) \rightarrow O(M)$ such that $B_t(u) = B(t)u$. So $\lambda(t)$ = $B(t, \overline{\lambda}(t))$.
Consequently, the pushforward of $(\partial/\partial t)$ by $B(t, \overline{\lambda}(t))$ includes both $(B_t)_*\left(\partial/\partial t\right)_{\overline{\lambda}}$ and a contribution from $B_*(\partial/\partial t) \equiv (dB/dt)$ in $ T_{B(t)}O(3,1)$. But we want a vector in $T_{\lambda(t)}O(M)$, not in $ T_{B(t)}O(3,1)$, so we first pushforward $(dB/dt)$ by $B_{-t}$ to get $(B_{-t})_*(dB/dt) \in T_IO(3,1)$, and then apply the $F_u: T_IO(3,1) \rightarrow T_uO(M)$ map which gives a tangent vector $F_u(a)$ to a curve $\lambda(t)$ in $O(M)$ passing through $u = (p,g)$ given by $(p, exp(ta)g)$.
(I was confused about what $F$ was initially, because H&E use boldface F for this map before, and in this passage they use italics.)
So, more cumbersomely, but with greater clarity (to me!), the equation in Hawking and Ellis could be written as:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_\lambda = (B_t)_* \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)_{\overline{\lambda}} + F((B_{-t})_*(B_*(\partial/\partial t))$$
